# How to 'condense' tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Beginner here.
I have a map:

```
map = [
    "......",
    "..##..",
    ".##.#.",
    "...###",
    "###.##",
]
```

`.` is a free path and `#` is an obstacle.

I managed to get a list of obstacles that looks like this:
`list_obstacle = [(3, 2), (4, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (5, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 4), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5)]`

but the final output should look like this:
`final list = [(3, 4, 2), (2, 3, 3), (5, 5, 3), (4, 6, 4), (1, 3, 5), (5, 6, 5)]`

My question is, how do I get a list of tuples with 3 elements from a list of tuples with two elements?

Thank you!

This is my best attempt yet :')

```
final_list = []
for obstacle, line in list_obstacle:
   for each_obstacle in range(obstacle, line)
   final_list.append(obstacle, each_obstacle, line)
print(final_list)
```

Comment: I assume in the 2 tuples the elements represent an `(x, y)` pair, but what does each of the elements in the 3 tuples represent?

Comment: Sorry, if tuple = (x, y, z) ; x is the start of an obstacle, y is the end of an obstacle and z is line

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.